# Determine if MS Word finished saving the document

Tags: silverlight-5.0, office-interop

I have a Silverlight 5.0 application and prvoide MS Word Automation functionality where the user can edit/add new document. I have gone through to MSDN pages but couldn't find any event that MS Word triggers after saving the document. The only event that talks about saving is the "DocumentBeforeSave" event that dosen't helps. I need to know when the MS Word finishes saving the document so that is it ready to save to server.

Can someone help me with this?

Any idea is very much approciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using MSWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var app = new MSWord.Application();
            var doc = app.Documents.Open(@"..\..\myDoc.docx");

            app.DocumentBeforeSave += app_DocumentBeforeSave;
        }

        static void app_DocumentBeforeSave(MSWord.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            app.DocumentBeforeSave -= app_DocumentBeforeSave;

            Cancel = true;
            Doc.Save();

            if(Doc.Saved){
                //Now you know the document has saved
            }

            app.DocumentBeforeSave += app_DocumentBeforeSave;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Save method doesn't run on a seperate thread, so it only returns once the Save is complete.

The **DocumentBeforeSave** event takes in a boolean call **Cancel** this is passed with the ref parameter, and setting it to true cancels the save that is about to take place.

You could set this to true, and then call **Save** yourself, this way you will know when the save has completed, as it runs on the same thread, something like this:

```
using MSWord = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace ConsoleApplication41
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var app = new MSWord.Application();
            var doc = app.Documents.Open(@"..\..\myDoc.docx");

            app.DocumentBeforeSave += app_DocumentBeforeSave;
        }

        static void app_DocumentBeforeSave(MSWord.Document Doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Cancel = true;
            Doc.Save();

            //Now you know the document has saved
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't call the Save() method of MS Word Automation, so we realy can't tell when was the word finish saving the file.

Comment: How do you save the file then?

Comment: Saving file is invoke by user by clicking the save (in menu bar) button or by clicking save when ask (in modal dialog). At this point, the 'DocumentBeforeSave' event will fire (document not yet save as the event name imply). We need an events that fire if MS Word finishes its save. As far as I know, the code sample above cannot be applied in Silverlight 5 application as it is not supported to add MS Word Reference to the project but rather using 'dynamic' and AutomationFactory class